# Printing individual items of a set

Tags: python

Is there a way to print an individual item from a set?  In the same way which you would print items of a list by referencing values between 0 and size of the list.

I was trying to reference items by using print(set_name[i]).  But was receiving an error for trying to reference an item in this way.  I was able to print the full set with print(set(name_set)), so there was not an issue with defining the values.

Comment: `for x in set(y): print(x)`. Indexing is not supported in `sets`

Comment: Also, the correct (idiomatic) way of printing items of a list is to loop through the list, not through the indices range.

Comment: share your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing is not supported in `set`. If you want to get an element from a `set`, you should either cast it to `list` (Note that `set` is unordered), or use an iterator:

```py
for element in <YOUR_SET>:
    if element == <DESIRED_VALUE>:
        break

print(element)
```